# calling method using CCCallFuncN or something

Tags: c++, objective-c, methods, cocos2d-x

Code:

*prog.h*

```
public:

virtual bool init();  
static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
CREATE_FUNC(ProgScene);
void spriteMoveFinished(CCNode* sender);

void endCallback(CCObject* pSender);
void endCallbackWork(CCNode* pSender);
```

*prog.cpp*

```
void ProgScene::spriteMoveFinished(CCNode* sender)
{
    CCMessageBox("Sprite Move Finished","Sprite Move Finished");
    this->runAction(CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget( this, callfuncN_selector(ProgScene::endCallbackWork)));  // WORK
 // this->runAction(CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget( this, callfuncN_selector(ProgScene::endCallback)));  // NOT WORK
}

void ProgScene::endCallback(CCObject* pSender)
{
    ...
    CCMessageBox("From endCallback","From endCallback");
}

void ProgScene::endCallbackWork(CCNode* sender)
{
    ...
    CCMessageBox("from endCallbackWork","from endCallbackWork");
}
```

I'm a beginner in cpp, please help me.

How can i call method endCallback from method `actionWithTarget` ?
When i use

```
this->runAction(CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget( this, callfuncN_selector(ProgScene::endCallback)));
```

it returns:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall ProgScene::* )(cocos2d::CCObject *)' to 'cocos2d::SEL_CallFuncN'
1>        Pointers to members have different representations; cannot cast between them
```

`endCallbackWork` is good working with

```
this->runAction(CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget( this, callfuncN_selector(ProgScene::endCallbackWork)));
```

Maybe I can use another way than the following ?

```
this->runAction(CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget( this, callfuncN_selector(ProgScene::endCallback)));
```

Comment: You should put the code declaring `actionWithTarget`, `calfuncN_selector` and `cocos2d::SEL_CallFuncN`.

Comment: why can´t you use the syntax that is working? what is the problem?

Comment: The same code works fine on my simulator,but                     'this->runAction(CCCallFuncN::create( this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::endCallback)));' is a better choice in new version of cocos2d-x.

Comment: it is because the CallfuncN (N stands for Node) requires a function which took a CCNode* as input. the one NOT WORK tooks an CCObjet* as an input and callfuncN_selector cannot do the wrong type casting. if you want to use the NOT WORK one , use CCCallfuncO and callfuncO_selector.